# Solve differential equation by integrating factor

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I have the differential equation $$2\frac{dy}{dx}+3y=e^{-2x}-5$$

I have determined that this needs solving using the integrating factor method.

My workings out are in the image provided.

Are my workings out correct so far? My main question is, how will I integrate with respect for $x$?

$$\int e^{3x/2} \times e^{-2x}-\frac{5}{2}e^{3x/2}~~dx+c$$

this again is shown at the bottom of my workings out.

after integrating this I will then be able to solve for $y$.

Thank you

[My workings out for the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlNSP.jpg)

Comment: Hint: use index laws and then integrate the exponentials like usual.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**
$$\int e^{kx}dx=\frac{1}{k}e^{kx}+c$$
where $k$ is any constant. Ask for more detail if you're still stuck :)

Answer (score 1):

$$2y'+3y=e^{-2x}-5$$
$$y'+\dfrac 23y=\dfrac 12 (e^{-2x}-5)$$
$$(ye^{3x/2})'=\dfrac {e^{3x/2}}2 (e^{-2x}-5)$$
$$ye^{3x/2}=\int \dfrac {e^{3x/2}}2 (e^{-2x}-5)dx$$
Don't forget the factor $1/2$:
$$ye^{3x/2}= \color {red}{\dfrac 12} \int (e^{-x/2}-5e^{3x/2})dx$$

Now to integrate use this result:
$$\int e^{ax}dx=\dfrac 1 a\int \,\,d(e^{ax})= \dfrac {e^{ax}}{a}+K$$

---

**Edit1**:
Integration gives us:
$$ye^{3x/2}= {\dfrac 12} \int (e^{-x/2}-5e^{3x/2})dx$$
$$ye^{3x/2}= {\dfrac 12}(-2e^{-x/2}-\dfrac {10}3e^{3x/2})+K$$
$$ye^{3x/2}= -e^{-x/2}-\dfrac {5}3e^{3x/2}+K$$

$$y=e^{-3x/2}( -e^{-x/2}-\dfrac {5}3e^{3x/2})+Ke^{-3x/2}$$
And finally :

$$\boxed {y= -e^{-2x}-\dfrac {5}3+Ke^{-3x/2}}$$

Comment: apologies for asking for more information. How would I integrate this result?

Comment: You mean the integral ? @clh99

Comment: I added more lines in my answer @clh99

Comment: yes I now understand how to get to (^3/2)y=1/2∫(^−/2−5^3/2). I actually calculated a very similar result im just unsure on the rules which turn e^-x/2 into -2e^x/2. and the rule that brings in the 10/3 part. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I added a complete answer @clh99 Take a look at the edit in my answer.

Comment: thank you, Im going to try and understand this

Comment: Yoy're very welcome. @clh99